# Update notmuch after sending an email in neomutt

Tags: neomutt, notmuch

What's the recommended way to update the notmuch database to include the newly sent email right after sending it in neomutt so that the email shows up in the index right after it has been sent? I can't seem to find a straight answer to that question online / in the neomutt documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the documentation

You should `set nm_record = yes` and `set nm_record_tags = "inbox,sent,me,read"`

(I personally keep my `sent` emails in my `inbox`)